# Save uncorrupted information from corrupted files

Tags: download, file-corruption

My university network is terrible (around 1 Mb/s down) and has too much activity, so large files usually get corrupted when I try to download them. I've tried to download the same 2.8 GB file several times to no avail, and I've experienced difficulty with smaller files as well.

Note that my university blocks the port used for torrents, and I'd also just like a solution for direct downloads.

Is there any way to save undamaged parts of the file each time I attempt to download it, and then once I have all the pieces after several downloads, put them all together?

Comment: You can download a torrent on any port you want.  So I very much doubt your university blocks students form using torrent software based on the port itself.  But if this happens with smaller files you have not analyzed the problem correctly.

Comment: There is no single port used for torrents.  Most likely they are using content filtering.  Have you tried a download manager?  If we knew the specific file(s) we might provide an alternative source that might be better for you.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to "download" the files?

Comment: Direct download.

Answer (score 0):

You can use download managers where it will split the file download and also provides where it left of options for file download.

Comment: **I have never heard of using a download manager on a network share.**

Answer (score 0):

Even in those conditions (low bandwidth and high activity), there's no reason why your files should be getting corrupted. That's probably happening due to a misconfiguration in the protocol properties either on your machine or the routing.

The best option you have is to use a download manager, as referred by Vembu, however even that is not a guarantee of integrity.

You can, however, change the port your BitTorrent client uses. But they are probably blocking the BitTorrent protocol directly through content analysis, not the port, which can be avoided by using a tunnel.